# What is the usefulness of the angle and direction of the sun parameters in hillshade?

Tags: raster, r, dem, hillshade

These parameters refer to the angle as of elevation and direction of the sun hypothetically to the hillshade but why does that must have any importance?

Comment: yes, i used to work with it in GRASS but can't figure out how to do it with R.Also i dont see how it deserves votedown.

Comment: You've tagged raster and r - could you edit your question and indicated the function you're using, and what results you're looking for?